# Call function from different directory C

Tags: c, function, directory, call

I was wondering if there is a way to call a C function in directory /home/dec/file1.C

```
int add( int a, int b){
c=a+b;
return c; }
```

, from a C file in the directory /home/work/file2.C

```
#include "file1.h"
sum = add(1,2);
```

So when I call add, it doesn't recognise that there is a function add in the other directory, but when I put them in the same directory, the program works.

I looked around but I only see how to call when the file is in the same directory, using an #include.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can move with chdir on linux

Comment: C functions don't really reside in a directory.. you mean a source file? Are you compiling then linking these source files together?

Comment: C functions are not located in directories. Do you mean an executable or a compilation unit in this directory?

Comment: so what should I do as when I do include, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Thank you all who helped. But I had to link each and every file individually. So I used gcc file1.o file2.o. And it worked. If anyone else stumbles on to this question, this might be helpful. I am posting this as an answer because it worked for me. But if someone has some explanation on this topic or some links, please feel free to share.